# Sporadic Mouse Location?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that takes a downscaled picture of the screen(1024x576), and wherever the user clicks on the picturebox, their mouse will move there on the actual screen. The problem I've ran into is that the mouse position seems to be sporadic. I used trial and error to get the mouse to move to the "stop" button in Visual studio when I clicked on the button in the screenshot, which worked. However, I then tried clicking on a scroll bar, and it doesn't click the right spot. Shouldn't the difference with each axis be static? I don't understand why this is only half-working.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(rawScreenBMP);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, rawScreenBMP.Size);
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(downscaledBMP);
    graphics.DrawImage(rawScreenBMP, new RectangleF(0, 0, downscaledBMP.Width, downscaledBMP.Height));

    pictureBox1.Image = downscaledBMP;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    RemoteClick(e.X, e.Y);
    Console.WriteLine(e.X.ToString() + " " + e.Y.ToString());
}

public static void RemoteClick(int locx, int locy)
{
    Console.WriteLine((locx + 390).ToString() + " " + (locy+30).ToString());
    SetCursorPos(locx + 390, locy + 30);
    //adding 390 for X and 30 for Y seemed to get the cursor in the right position when I clicked the debug "stop" button. But it clicks in the incorrect spot elsewhere
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(Cursor.Position);
}
```

Comment: Is this for a remote desktop client? If so will it only ever be used on one resolution? Also the code will not work, you need to work out a ratio, if you add 360 every time, if you click pixel 0 then you'll still not click the left, you'll click 360

Comment: Hey Alfie - Yes, this will eventually be made into a remote desktop client. How would you recommend calculating the resolution? I tried subtracting the difference between my monitor (1080p) and the picturebox (1024x576) and then adding the difference for x and y. This didn't seem to work. I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a ratio instead of static numbers, as they will not work, as per my comment

Instead, if the screen is 1920*1080 for example

```
double ratiox = (1920 / 1024);
double ratioy = (1080 / 576);
SetCursorPos(locx * ratiox, locy * ratioy);
```

Writing on a phone sorry if the code is inaccurate, but that's an example of how you work out the ratio

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but it seems to put my cursor at 0,0

Comment: Sorry I realised something a little wrong, give me a moment to change it :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks again for trying to help me ( ´ ▽ ` )ﾉ

Comment: Give it a go now and all should be well :)

Comment: Hm, it still seems to not be clicking in the right spot. I have no idea why. Here is the updated method http://i.imgur.com/nc9COOD.png

Comment: Here is the entire code. I still can't figure out why this wouldn't work, especially with your solution(which seemed in theory to make sense) https://pastebin.com/raw/83AA7dH8

Comment: 1920/1024 is exactly 1, as you divide it in ints. You should change that to 1920.0/1024.

Comment: locx * (int)ratiox is incorrect, you should round it at the very end like (int)(locx*ratiox+0.5). The main problem is probably mouse_event where you pass 0 as x and y argument.

Comment: Wow, I think your comment might have solved. I don't exactly understand how, but thank you so much Antonin!